# Difference between `Lazy.force` and `Lazy.force_val`

Tags: ocaml, lazy-evaluation

There are two forces in Lazy module:

---

> val force : 'a t -> 'a
>
> force x forces the suspension x and returns its result. If x has
>   already been forced, Lazy.force x returns the same value again without
>   recomputing it. If it raised an exception, the same exception is
>   raised again. Raise Undefined if the forcing of x tries to force x
>   itself recursively.

---

> val force_val : 'a t -> 'a
>
> force_val x forces the suspension x and returns its result. If x has
>   already been forced, force_val x returns the same value again without
>   recomputing it. Raise Undefined if the forcing of x tries to force x
>   itself recursively. If the computation of x raises an exception, it is
>   unspecified whether force_val x raises the same exception or
>   Undefined.

---

It seems the only diff is

> If the computation of x raises an exception, it is
>   unspecified whether force_val x raises the same exception or
>   Undefined.`

From my understanding, we don't know whether it will raise original exception or `Undefined` if we use `force_val`.

Then what's the point behind this? Why make it this way? Any good we can get from `force_val`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess it is for performance purpose.
If you care about getting the same error, use `force`. If you don't but want better performance, use `force_val`.

As you can see [here](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/trunk/stdlib/camlinternalLazy.ml), `force` does the same thing as `force_val` but performs an extra access to memory in case an exception occurs.

After reading the source and running some tests, the behaviour of these two functions seems different from what the doc says : If you use only `force`, you will always get the original error but if you use `force_val` the first call will raise the original exception and all subsequent calls to `force_val` **or `force`** will raise `Undefined`.

**EDIT:** Actually, I'm not sure that using `force_val` instead of `force` improves performance since `force` is a primitive and `force_val` is not.

Comment: let me clarify more after I did my study at the source code and experiments. basically, `force_val` will not store the exception to the lazy var. first time force_val, it will let whatever exception throw and from 2nd time on, it will throw only `Undefined`. `force` is different as it stores the original exception and always throw the same exception as it was stored. The experiment you did is because you run `force_val` first, as it never store the exception, the exn branch of lazy var is always Undefined. So after, you call `force` on the same lazy var, it will always raise `Undefined`.

Comment: If the documentation differs from the actual behaviour as specified in the code, should someone bring it to the attention of the dev-team?